# abrir navegador web desde tarea programada de windows

Tags: windows10, windows-server

agradezco su ayuda para la siguiente situación

quiero tener una tarea programada de Windows, que por una definición de tiempo por ejemplo cada a las 8 am me ejecute un archivo bat, que a su vez contiene la apertura del navegador en una pagina especifica.

el archivo por ejemplo apuntado a google navega.bat con la siguiente linea

```
START firefox.exe google.com
```

al ejecutarlo sin la tarea programada todo funciona como necesito, pero desde la tarea programada no lo hace (no abre el navegador, en administrador de tareas si se ve el proceso) y en el historial del programador de tareas el resultado es exitoso.

me ayudan por favor, que puede suceder o si existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo. gracias

Comment: No creo que puedas hacer eso porque el task scheduler no levanta el entorno, y si lo hiciera te quedaría iniciado el navegador sin poder eliminarlo.
¿Lo que necesitás es que se navegue una página periódicamente, sin importar quien la ve?  Si ese es el caso, también necesitás que se ejecuten los scripts en el navegador o alcanza con que el servidor devuelva la página?

Comment: gracias por la respuesta.  si, requiero la ejecución periódicamente sin importar quien la vea y seria suficiente que el servidor devuelva la pagina que envió en la petición

Comment: tiene que ser a las 8 am??? o debe ser cuando entres al escritorio de windows???

Comment: y cual es el navegador de tu preferencia???

Comment: @avelo Te sirve el ejemplo que te dejé?  Así lo usamos nosotros.

Comment: si totalmente me sirvió el ejemplo. la programación de ejecución de la tarea se realiza a diferentes horas, segun se establece en el programador de tareas. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitás es que periódicamente se navegue una página, sin importar el resultado y sin tener la necesidad de ejecutar los scripts, te recomiendo que instales curl: https://curl.se/windows/.  Esta aplicación devuelve el contenido de una página, de forma similar al curl de linux.
Con esta app podrías agregar una tarea que ejecute una línea similar a esta:

```
curl https://www.programandoamedianoche.com
```

Suerte!

Comment: funciono correcto. gracia